# prove intersections of subdomains of an integral domain is a subdomain

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that the intersection of subdomains of an integral domain D is again a subdomain of D

Progress: I know that if that question were instead about the intersection of a collection of subgroups, H_i with i in a set I, of a group G, then you'd need to show that if a and b are in the intersection, so is ab (for closure); also, the identity of G is in the intersection; also, if a is in all H_i, so is its inverse in G. But I do not know how to adapt this to integral domains.

Comment: What exactly is your problem in proving this? What do you not understand? What did you already try?

Comment: Well I know that if that question were instead about the intersection of a collection of subgroups, H_i with i in a set I, of a group G, then you'd need to show that if a and b are in the intersection, so is ab (for closure); also, the identity of G is in the intersection; also, if a is in all H_i, so is its inverse in G. But I do not know how to adapt this to integral domains.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ be a ring and let $R_i, i \in \Delta,$ be a collection of subrings of $R$.

Claim: $\bigcap\limits_{i \in \Delta}R_i$ is also  a subring of $R$.

Since each $R_i$ is an additive subgroup of $R$, $\bigcap\limits_{i \in \Delta}R_i$ is also an additive subgroup of $R$.

Let $a, b \in \bigcap\limits_{i \in \Delta}R_i$. Then $a, b \in R_i$ for each $i \Rightarrow ab \in R_i$ for each $i \Rightarrow ab \in \bigcap\limits_{i \in \Delta}R_i$.

Comment: Can you expand on this a little? I am not following you. Sorry!

Comment: exactly at which point you are having trouble?

Comment: unfortunately, the whole thing. What is the delta? Also, wouldnt I also have to show more than just this?

Comment: what is your definition of subring? I assume that it is an additive subgroup of $R$ which is closed under multiplication. $\Delta$ is an index set.